# Jenkins to slave machine connection got broken after updating the SSL certs?

Tags: java, windows, jenkins, iis

Recently the cert got expired both on Jenkins server (Linux) and IIS server (windows) and we have imported the new certs for both Jenkins and remote slave.

post that it was able to connect when we launch through browser (but pop up with java - `(The certificate is not valid and cannot be used to verify the identity of this website)`  and if we install Jenkins as a service on windows machine it was in starting state (not proceeding with the Running state) and unable to start the Jenkins as slave in logs 
i can see this error as following:

"`Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"`

Comment: Please verify as self-signed certs or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your certs are not correct. Make sure the values for CN and hostname on the cert you imported are the same as the old cert. Make sure you have the intermediate and root certificates imported/trusted as well, as those may have changed with the new certs.

Windows: certlm to check that the intermediate and root certificates are also trusted.